# Why does indexing a string inside of a recursive call yield a different result?

Tags: indexing, slice, d

In my naive implementation of edit-distance finder, I have to check whether the last characters of two strings match:

```d
ulong editDistance(const string a, const string b) {
    if (a.length == 0)
        return b.length;
    if (b.length == 0)
        return a.length;

    const auto delt = a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1;

    import std.algorithm : min;

    return min(
        editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b[0 .. $ - 1]) + delt, 
        editDistance(a, b[0 .. $ - 1]) + 1, 
        editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b) + 1
    );
}
```

This yields the expected results but if I replace `delt` with its definition it always returns 1 on non-empty strings:

```d
ulong editDistance(const string a, const string b) {
    if (a.length == 0)
        return b.length;
    if (b.length == 0)
        return a.length;

    //const auto delt = a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1;

    import std.algorithm : min;

    return min(
        editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b[0 .. $ - 1]) + a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1, //delt, 
        editDistance(a, b[0 .. $ - 1]) + 1, 
        editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b) + 1
    );
}
```

Why does this result change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators have different precedence from what you expect. In `const auto delt = a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1;` there is no ambiguity, but in `editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b[0 .. $ - 1]) + a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1`, there is (seemingly).

Simplifying:

```d
auto tmp = editDistance2(a[0..$-1], b[0..$-1]);
return min(tmp + a[$-1] == b[$-1] ? 0 : 1),
    //...
);
```

The interesting part here is parsed as `(tmp + a[$-1]) == b[$-1] ? 0 : 1`, and `tmp + a[$-1]` is not equal to `b[$-1]`. The solution is to wrap things in parentheses:

```d
editDistance(a[0 .. $ - 1], b[0 .. $ - 1]) + (a[$ - 1] == b[$ - 1] ? 0 : 1)
```